# MVVM approach for Triggers off dependency property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I've created a helper class to host custom Dependency properties.  I have created a custom UserControl object that's somewhat complex and updates it's layout rather frequently.  I'd like to trigger an animation when one of the Attached Properties changes its value.

Here's an example of the helper class that hosts a DP.

```
namespace testProject
{
  public class MenuHelper : DependencyObject
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMenuReversedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "IsMenuReversed",
      typeof(Boolean),
      typeof(MenuHelper),
      new PropertyMetadata(false));
  }
}
```

And here's an example of how i'd like to have referenced the DP:

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="testProject:MenuHelper.IsMenuReversed" Value="True">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bouncy_Bar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="-1" Duration="0:0:.002"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="testProject:MenuHelper.IsMenuReversed" Value="False">
        <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bouncy_Bar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1" Duration="0:0:.002"/>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

I realize that I cannot do the above code since the triggers collection can only house Event triggers. Which brings me to my question:

What is the appropriate solution to this problem?

I attempted to make a RoutedEvent to inform me of a change in IsMenuReversed but then realized i cannot check the current value of the DP in xaml(as far as i know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i came up with so far is to just have two separate RoutedEvents. One for each state.  I'm not a big fan of this solution, so i welcome any other feedback that someone may have.

Here's the Helper class with the DP that fires one of two different routed events:

```
    namespace TestProject
    {
      public class MenuHelper : DependencyObject
      {
        public static void SetIsMenuReversed(UIElement element, Boolean value)
        {
          if (GetIsMenuReversed(element) != value)
          {
            if (value == true)
              element.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MenuHelper.MenuIsReversedEvent));
            else
              element.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MenuHelper.MenuIsNotReversedEvent));
            element.SetValue(IsMenuReversedProperty, value);
          }
        }
        public static bool GetIsMenuReversed(DependencyObject obj)
        {
          return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsMenuReversedProperty);
        }

        public static readonly RoutedEvent MenuIsReversedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
          "MenuIsReversed",
          RoutingStrategy.Direct,
          typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
          typeof(MenuHelper));

        public static readonly RoutedEvent MenuIsNotReversedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
          "MenuIsNotReversed",
          RoutingStrategy.Direct,
          typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
          typeof(MenuHelper)); 
      }
    }
```

And here is the Xaml that listens for the routed events and triggers a related storyboard for each one:

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="testProject:MenuHelper.MenuIsReversed">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bouncy_Bar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="-1" Duration="0:0:.002"/>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="testProject:MenuHelper.MenuIsNotReversed">
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bouncy_Bar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1" Duration="0:0:.002"/>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

Please post alternative solutions if you have them :)